# Should Webpack HTML templates have hash in file name?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, caching

I'm new to bundling node.js apps with Webpack. I understand that hashes in filenames help with updating browser caches with new content.

Let's say I have the following `HtmlWebpackPlugin` config and express route:

```
// webpack.front-end.config.js
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ minify, template: path.resolve('./src/index.html'), filename: 'index.[hash].html', chunks: ['home'] })
]

// server.js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.abc1234.html');
});
```

Then I change my content in `index.html` and it generates `index.def3456.html`.

How do I write my express route or change my webpack config so that I don't have to change the filename in the `res.sendFile()` call each time I change `index.html` content? Should I even have the hash in the `index.html`'s filename? I'm aware I can put `meta` tags in `index.html` to avoid browser caching, but that seems like it would slow down performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in using the hash here. The client is not requesting the html file directly so it doesn't really matter what you name the file. All the client sees is the `/` endpoint.